# cppcheck --includes-file option does not work

Tags: cppcheck

`cppcheck --includes-file=<filename> --enable=all --check-config <source code directory>` does not work. Cppcheck says unable to find the header files.

`<filename>` has the directory where the header file is located.

If I give the same command as follows:
`cppcheck -I <path to header file> --enable=all --check-config <source code directory>`, then it works fine.

I find this very strange. Any suggestions?

Comment: running cppcheck v1.52 on Ubuntu 14.04 desktop

Answer (score 0):

sounds strange. I recommend that you upgrade cppcheck, your version is quite old. latest cppcheck version is 1.68.